# How to Change row to column

Tags: excel, vba

I'm novice to the excel macros. My requirement is like:

For given matrix which having single column with multiple rows I need to change this rows into column in next sheet(says sheet2).

```
Col1
xyz
pqr
abc
```

This need to be changed rows in sheet2 as follows:

```
xyz    pqr    abc
```

This is what I have tried:

```
Sub rowToCol()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim n As Integer
    n = Application.WrokSheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A2:A4"), "Col1")

    For i = 1 To n
       Sheet2.Cells(i, 1) = Sheeti.Cells(1, i)
    Next
End rowToCol
```

Comment: Why do you need code for this? Simply copy the range and do a pastespecial transpose :)

Comment: If you still need VBA code then record a macro for above and then amend it to suit your needs... :)

Comment: actually What I asked i't just a part of my other requirements...I need it to write the VBA Code.. Kindly help me how I can Write that

Comment: See my second comment. Also please show us what have you tried? Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: SiddharthRout : I have edited what I have tried...

Comment: Ok, so tell us what doesn't work in your current solution? (Aside from **`Wrok`** `sheetFunction`...)

Comment: @Samraan: That is not what I suggested :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett : It's not Writing to the sheet2

Comment: you need Pivot: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh243933%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint and running in debug mode to figure out why things are not happening the way you expect?

Comment: I have tried for debugging and I found that this statement--> Sheet1.Cells(i,1) = Sheet2.Cells(1,i) is not executing...It getting skipped

Comment: ... You're doing wrong way: `Sheet2.Cells(i, 1) = Sheet1.Cells(1, i)` ...

Comment: why are you doing a `countif` ?

Comment: Did you find any of what was posted useful?

Answer (score 0):

Simple Recorded macro for transpose.

```
Sub Macro2()

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Select
    Range("A" & 2).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy


    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It is always convenient to avoid `Select`ing objects/ranges, unless strictly needed. So you would use references to those objects/ranges, in your case as

```
Sub trnsp()
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range
    Set rng1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A4")
    rng1.Copy
    Set rng2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
    rng2.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True
End Sub
```

You would change the sheet names and ranges as needed.